# How to write regex in JS for first 2 characters can be digit or alphabet and followed by hyphen and then 6 digit number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to create the regex for following format:

```
12-345678  Matches
AB-345678  Matches

$12-345678 Failed
%%-SDdfdf  Failed
```

1. First 2 characters should be alphabet or digit example AA or 12
2. Third character should be compulsory -(hyphen) and
3. Last six characters should be digit
4. String should not be greater than 9 characters long

I have written following Regex but it is failing:

```
$('#customer-number').keyup(function(){
$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/^(d{2}|[a-z]{2})\-\\d{6}/,'$1-'))
});
```

But the Regex fails:

```
/^(d{2}|[a-z]{2})\-\\d{6}/
```

I am new to regex, please help me

Comment: `d` is not the same as `\d`. ``\\d`` will match a ``\d`` char sequence, not a digit. `[a-z]` only matches lowercase, did you mean `[A-Z]` or `[A-Za-z]`? You also miss `$` at the end of the pattern if you want to match the entire string. Also, the regex looks like a validating regex, but you are using it in a `replace` method, could you please clarify?

Comment: Is `A1` or `1A` allowed for the first 2 characters?

Comment: Actually not allowed!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}-\d{6}/
```

**Where**

`^` asserts position at start of a line

`a-z` a single character in the range between a (index 97) and z (index 122) (case sensitive)

`A-Z` a single character in the range between A (index 65) and Z (index 90) (case sensitive)

`0-9` a single character in the range between 0 (index 48) and 9 (index 57) (case sensitive)

`{2}` Quantifier — Matches exactly 2 times

`-` matches the character - literally

`\d` matches a digit (equal to [0-9])

`{6}` Quantifier — Matches exactly 6 times

**Demo:**

```js
console.log(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}-\d{6}/.test('12-345678'));  //true
console.log(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}-\d{6}/.test('AB-345678'));  //true
console.log(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}-\d{6}/.test('$12-345678')); //false
console.log(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}-\d{6}/.test('%%-SDdfdf'));  //false
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed `\` before **d**, you need to add `A-Z` for uppercase and you added a `\` that escape the other `\`.

```
^(\d{2}|[a-zA-Z]{2})\-\d{6}
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/SEQGOq/1

Answer (score 1):

Try This regex `/^([a-zA-Z]{2}|[0-9]{2})-\d{6}/g`

```js
function matchString() { 
        var test1 = "11-122121";
        var test2 = "1a-122121"; 
        var test3 = "aa-122121"; 
        var result1 = test1.match(/^([a-zA-Z]{2}|[0-9]{2})-\d{6}/g); 
        var result2 = test2.match(/^([a-zA-Z]{2}|[0-9]{2})-\d{6}/g); 
        var result3 = test3.match(/^([a-zA-Z]{2}|[0-9]{2})-\d{6}/g); 
        document.write("Output1 : " + result1 + "<br>");         
        document.write("Output2 : " + result2 + "<br>");
        document.write("Output3 : " + result3);
    } matchString();
```